# Поиск по конкретному слову в списке, а не по части слова

Tags: python, файлы

У меня есть список с артистами, и мне нужно иногда проверять есть ли артист в этом списке. Но вот проблема, иногда по ошибке он выдает неверный ответ (Пишет что есть артист, хотя его нет), из-за того что часть ника артиста есть в нике другого артиста:

```
whitelist = open('list.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
whitelist = whitelist.read()

if 'SPA' in whitelist:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

В списке есть артист "VSPAK" из-за чего пишет "True", хотя самого "SPA" нет. Как то можно сделать так чтобы он искал именно слово, а не его часть?

Comment: ну так вы читайте не весь файл "сплошняком", а хотя бы построчно (надеюсь, у вас каждый артист на отдельной строке). например, `whitelist = whiltelist.readlines()`

Comment: Артисты хоть и на отдельной строке, но при readlines() всегда теперь выдает False

Comment: @strawdog а какая разница как читать, хоть построчно, хоть целиком, SPA все равно будет в VSPAK

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй регулярные выражения:

```
import re

whitelist = open('list.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
whitelist = whitelist.read()

pattern = "SKA"

if re.findall(r"\b"+pattern+r"\b", whitelist ):
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

`\b` означает границу слова.

Comment: Можно ли как то артистов из файла поместить в список python, это облегчит задачу) Просто там есть артисты с ником из двух слов, а хочется чтобы искало именно этого артиста, и единственный способ это сделать как по мне это список whitelist = []

Comment: как-то можно поместить конечно :)